# Application property value from build.gradle file

Tags: spring-boot, properties, gradlew

I have a spring-boot application and run it with gradle. 
In my build.gradle I wrote

```
def buildPort
task calculateServerPort {
    def os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    javaexec {
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        main = 'com.kiporov.ServerPortConfigurationBean'
        standardOutput = os
    }
    buildPort = os.toString()
    println 'New Server Port ' + buildPort
    project.ext.myport = buildPort

}

processResources {
    dependsOn(calculateServerPort)
    filesMatching("**/application.yml") {
        expand(project: properties)
    }
}

bootRun {
    addResources = false
}
```

I normally get New Server Port from ServerPortConfigurationBean. In log I see

```
New Server Port 59981

:second-subsystem-service:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:second-subsystem-service:calculateServerPort UP-TO-DATE
:second-subsystem-service:processResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':second-subsystem-service:processResources'.
> Could not copy file 'C:\Users\novde\IdeaProjects\diplom-ver2\diplom\second-subsystem-service\src\main\resource\application.yml' to 'C:\Users\novde\IdeaProjects\diplom-ver2\diplom\second-subsystem-service\build\resources\main\application.yml'.
```

I don't understand the problem. Why execution process cannot copy the file?

**UPDATE**
I tried to run with `--stacktrace` and I see this log.
My gradlew version  3.4.1

```
C:\Users\novde\IdeaProjects\diplom-ver2\diplom\second-subsystem-service>gradlew bootRun --stacktrace
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy and 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
The plugin id 'spring-boot' is deprecated. Please use 'org.springframework.boot' instead.
The plugin id 'spring-boot' is deprecated. Please use 'org.springframework.boot' instead.
The plugin id 'spring-boot' is deprecated. Please use 'org.springframework.boot' instead.
The plugin id 'spring-boot' is deprecated. Please use 'org.springframework.boot' instead.
New Server Port 56360

:second-subsystem-service:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:second-subsystem-service:calculateServerPort UP-TO-DATE
:second-subsystem-service:processResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':second-subsystem-service:processResources'.
> Could not copy file 'C:\Users\novde\IdeaProjects\diplom-ver2\diplom\second-subsystem-service\src\main\resource\application.yml' to 'C:\Users\novde\IdeaProjects\diplom-ver2\diplom\second-subsystem-service\
build\resources\main\application.yml'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':second-subsystem-service:processResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:256)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:253)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy file 'C:\Users\novde\IdeaProjects\diplom-ver2\diplom\second-subsystem-service\src\main\resource\application.yml' to 'C:\Users\novde\IdeaProjects\dip
lom-ver2\diplom\second-subsystem-service\build\resources\main\application.yml'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction$FileCopyDetailsInternalAction.processFile(FileCopyAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:85)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker.walkDir(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:171)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:149)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:24)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:648)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:650)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:458)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DelegatingCopySpecInternal.walk(DelegatingCopySpecInternal.java:236)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction.execute(FileCopyAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask.copy(AbstractCopyTask.java:179)
        at org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.copy(ProcessResources.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 49: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 49, column 40.
   /* Generated by SimpleTemplateEngine */
                                          ^

1 error

        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ChainingTransformer.transform(ChainingTransformer.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.open(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyFile(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:74)
        ... 107 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 47.613 secs
```

Comment: Can you rerun it with `--stacktrace` and post output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem.
This is solution

**build.gradle**

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
def buildPort
task calculateServerPort {
    if (isCalculatePort) {
        def os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        javaexec {
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
            // calculate your port here
            main = 'com.kiporov.ServerPortConfigurationBean'
            standardOutput = os
        }
        // if you really need business logic in Java for calculation, you could use the javaExec task in here
        buildPort = os.toString()
        println 'New Server Port ' + buildPort
        project.ext.buildPort = buildPort // make it available as project.property her
    }
}
task initConfig(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn(calculateServerPort)
    if (isCalculatePort) {
        from('src/main/resource') {
            include '**/*.yml'
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [myPort: buildPort])
        }
        into 'build/resources/main'

        includeEmptyDirs = false
    }
    //with dataContent
}

bootRun {
    dependsOn(initConfig)
}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: @myPort@
```